# Where are all the Caldari COSMOS agents located?

Tags: eve-online

I'm having some difficulties finding updated sources of information on Caldari COSMOS agents, so I would like to know, where are all the Caldari COSMOS agents located and what are their levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the CCP Wiki "EVEolopedia" on [COSMOS Mission constellations](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/COSMOS_constellation#Caldari).

Okkelen Costellation,

Airmia, Friggi, Ihakana, Ishisomo, Otitoh, Otomainen, Sakkikainen and Vahunomi systems.